# How to create Fluid Extension Provider in TYPO3 v9 (2018)

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

We're currently struggling at creating Extension Provider with FluidPowered Typo3. This tutorial is outdated an we can't find any solution how to make Fluid Extension Provider from scratch. Also the 'builder' extension is not compatible with Typo3 versions higher than 8.5.

https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/provider-extension/generating-extensions.html

Is there any possibility to create Fluid Powered Extension Provider with Typo3 v. 9? Where are informations about custom extension provider files structure, controllers etc. ? The last post on Fluid website is from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this page instead: [FluidTemplate documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html)

And yes its short, but everything I could write is at that page. ;)

Comment: And maybe this one too: https://packagist.org/packages/friendsoftypo3/extension-builder#dev-master